# PHP cURL cookies not maintaining

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I want to cURL an address multiple times and share the cookie file between them. The code I use is like bellow:

```
<?php

$count = $argv[1];

echo $count;

while($count > 0){

$ch = curl_init("somewhere.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "./cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "./cookeis.txt");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );

$count--;

echo $count;

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo curl_exec($ch) . "\n\n";

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

but after running the code, I don't see the result of requesting page multiple times over web browser. The cookies file is filled although.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

somewhere  FALSE   /       FALSE   0       PHPSESSID       something
```

where is the wrongness? TG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. These lines of code should have been added:

```
...
$cookie = session_name() . '=' . time();
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
...
```

TG.